# Seeking passenger list for SS Wittekind which landed in Baltimore, Maryland in 1910

Tags: poland, 1910s, manifest, maryland

Looking for the Passengers list on the SS Witteland.  Landed in Baltimore, Maryland on June 11, 1910.  Name Marcin Glowacki.  His final destination was Grand Rapids Michigan. Born November 4, 1892.

Comment: Questions like this can be improved by telling us where you got the information that the passenger arrived in the USA.  If we know what record you already have on hand, we can suggest other records to check that might lead to the passenger list.  Plus, including the source information of whatever you have shows research effort.

Answer (score 4):

I suspect the vessel you are looking for is actually the ***SS Wittekind***, which arrived in Baltimore on 26 May 1910.  The [passenger list](https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/3:1:3QS7-89SD-CNKK?i=313&cc=2018318) is available on Familysearch, and Marcin Glowacki, aged 18, is listed among the passengers (2nd on the list).

---

As an interesting aside, the SS Wittekind was seized by the United States in 1917, eventually becoming the cargo and transport ship [USS Freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USS_Freedom_(ID-3024)).